# Why raspbian has /usr/sbin/service?

Tags: raspbian, systemd, init, upstart

I know that Raspbian, being a Debian derived distribution, uses `systemd` as its `init` system, but the question is, why is there the binary `/usr/sbin/service` from the upstart init system? Is there to provide compatibility?

ps. Package upstart has never been uninstalled

Answer (score 3):

It is there for compatibility. While the OS has switched to systemd, not all packages have been adapted for `systemd`, so some amount of backwards compatibility is available to run the older package scripts.

The `service` command is also helpful for backwards compatible with humans who expect the command to exist and work, even if it ends up restarting a systemd service instead of an Upstart service.